# Unable to render the variables inside controller function to view

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angularjs-1.6

Here is my code on [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RsaMh8sump81qqrJHHl1?p=info)

I am unable to get the view on `orders.html` from the controller `OrdersController` inside `controllerOrder.js` file. For some reason I am not able to render the variables of `OrdersController` controller onto the view.

Comment: you should edit your question to include the code. All questions should be self sufficient without external links.

Comment: there is no code in your plunker link.

Comment: There is no customers.html file, your script.js file is empty, your styles.css file is empty, and your index.html doesn't reference AngularJS.

Comment: oh no, i am working on it. Something's not right here.

Comment: Ah, I didn't freeze it before posting the link earlier. Is it fixed now? Are you able to see files?

Comment: yes, the files are there.

Comment: You have `<script src="controllers/controllerOrder.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="controllerOrder.js"></script>` in your `index.html` file :).

Comment: Fixed that typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/HSWw3Tnr5ZCLfkM045ha?p=preview).

In `controllerCustomer.js` file, it was `controllersAs: 'OrdersCtrl'` instead of `controllerAs: 'OrdersCtrl'`. And answer to your question is yes, it is redundant to specify the controller in the template as well.

Generally, UI Router is regarded as a better solution for AngularJS routing. You can checkout this [link](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router) for more details.

Comment: That's a great fix. But why do I have to wrap it around the controller. I have already given the file orders.html a controller in the Myapp.config. Then why do I have to call the controller again manually there? Won't this be redundant?

Comment: I found another typo that is responsible for all of this. I will update the answer right now :).

Comment: Amazing. They should really give syntax error or something in the console. That one letter made me waste so much time on this.